# Wicket: Openlayers Integration & Open Streetmaps Layer

Tags: java, dictionary, mapping, wicket

I want to include a open-street-map widget into my apache wicket application. Im using the [wicket-contrib-openlayers](http://wicketstuff.org/confluence/display/STUFFWIKI/wicket-contrib-openlayers) component from [wicket-stuff](http://wicketstuff.org) and the following code:

```
    List<Layer> layers = new ArrayList<Layer>();
    Layer layerOSMTilesAtHome = new OSM("Osmarender", OSMLayer.TilesAtHome);
    Layer layerOSMMapnik = new OSM("Mapnik", OSMLayer.Mapnik);
    Layer layerOSMCycleMap = new OSM("CycleMap", OSMLayer.CycleMap);

    layers.add(layerOSMMapnik);
    layers.add(layerOSMTilesAtHome);        
    layers.add(layerOSMCycleMap);

    HashMap<String, String> mapOptions = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Bounds boundsExtend = new Bounds(new LonLat(-20037508.34, -20037508.34), new LonLat(20037508.34, 20037508.34));     
    mapOptions.put("maxExtent", boundsExtend.getJSconstructor());
    mapOptions.put("projection", "new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913')");
    mapOptions.put("displayProjection", "new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326')");
    mapOptions.put("units", "'meters'");
    mapOptions.put("maxResolution", "156543");
    mapOptions.put("numZoomLevels", "18");

    OpenLayersMap map = new OpenLayersMap("map", layers, mapOptions);       

    map.addControl(Control.LayerSwitcher);
    map.addControl(Control.MousePosition);
    map.addControl(Control.KeyboardDefaults);   

    add(map);
```

This is a 1:1 copy of the SimpleOpenStreetMapExample from the component. The problem now is: How do I set the center of the map. I tried a

```
map.setCenter(new LonLat(5, 50), 13);
```

after the "add(map);" from the code above. This doesnt work, the map doesnt change at all. Im not sure what unit Lon and Lat have to be in, I also tried to convert them Mercator-System using this methods:

```
 private static double lon2Merc(double lon) {
    return 20037508.34*lon/180.0;
  }

  private static double lat2Merc(double lat) {
    lat = Math.log(Math.tan((90.0 + lat)*Math.PI/360.0))/(Math.PI/180.0);
    return 20037508.34*lat/180.0;
  }
```

But this doesnt help, nothing changes.

**So: Can anybody post a short example how to embedded a OSM-Map into Wicket and how to set the center and zoom-level?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of usage Openlayers in Wicket. Did you try this:
https://wicket-stuff.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/wicket-stuff/trunk/wicketstuff-core/openlayers-parent/openlayers-examples/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/openlayers/MapUsingWFSGetFeaturePage.java

?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether Wicket has any special requirements, but you can set zoom levels in OpenLayers either by specifying specific resolutions when you create the layer. Here's an example:

```
osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap", 
                "", {isBaseLayer: true, displayInLayerSwitcher: true, 
                zoomOffset: 13, resolutions: 
                [19.1092570678711, 9.55462853393555, 4.77731426696777, 
                2.38865713348389, 1.19432856674194, 0.5971642833709717]}),
```

Other maps providors may have different parameters in their APIs:

```
gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Satellite",
            {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, maxZoomLevel: 18, 
                minZoomLevel:13}
```

You can set the center of maps with the [setCenter function.](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setCenter)